# failing while sending bug email in emacs

Tags: emacs

C-cC-c,get this info:

Sending...terminated by signal: Broken pipe

I find paste a long file in text mode is wrong(GUI version is OK),
and want to send a bug email.

what should i config? sending mail in emacs is cool!

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emacs uses the `/usr/sbin/sendmail` command (specified by the `sendmail-program` variable) to deliver email you compose. You might be getting the error because your `sendmail` command is not working properly.

To resolve the issue you could try using the `sendmail` command directly (try `man sendmail`) to verify it really works. If it doesn't work properly, you should fix it and sending email from Emacs should start working.